# Is causality a consequence or a constraint in physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, causality, locality

I wonder if causality is a constraint that we must add to physical models (if needed), or is it a consequence of Lorentz invariance and locality (or something else). In other words, which properties should we impose to get causality for free?

Comment: IMHO this can be a bit subtle if one considers gravity. In fact, when a particle crosses a shockwave it experiences a time delay. This is something that can be computed with the standard Einstein-Hilbert action, but it turns out that when one thinks of possible higher-derivative corrections it may be possible that instead of a time delay one gets a time advance. In turn there is an argument that this breaks causality. In the end of the day this is one particular case in which causality is a constraint on such higher-derivative corrections. See details in https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5597.

Comment: It's a constraint. Gold references one example of the fact that innocent looking Lagrangians (with or without gravity) can easily be acausal. The bounds on couplings that you get from these thought experiments are all necessary conditions. The set of QFTs that have been proven to obey causality is probably not much bigger than the set of QFTs that have been exactly solved.